# Node.js node-apn module for Apple Push Notification stopped working after moving to Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

I am using node-apn module to avail of APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) to push notification to multiple devices. The local environment is Mac OS X Lion 10.7 and the code works perfectly fine when run at local server.Here's the snippet:

```
var apns = require('apn');

var options = {
    cert: __dirname + '/PushDevCertKey.pem',                       
    certData: null,                                
    key:  __dirname + '/PushDevCertKey.pem',                       
    keyData: null,                                 
    passphrase: 'admin',                              
    ca: null,                                      
    pfx: null,                                     
    pfxData: null,                                 
    gateway: 'gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com',     
    port: 2195,                                    
    rejectUnauthorized: true,                      
    enhanced: true,                                
    errorCallback: apnErrorCallback,                      
    cacheLength: 100,                              
    autoAdjustCache: true,                         
    connectionTimeout: 0
}

var apnsConnection = new apns.Connection(options);
var note = new apns.Notification();

note.expiry = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 3600; 
note.badge = 1;
note.sound = 'ping.aiff';
note.alert = 'you have a new message';
note.payload = {'rid': roomId}; 

apnsConnection.pushNotification(note, deviceTokenArray);

// i handle these events to confirm the notification gets
// transmitted to the APN server or find error if any

function log(type) {
    return function() {
        console.log(type, arguments);
    }
}

apnsConnection.on('error', log('error'));
apnsConnection.on('transmitted', log('transmitted'));
apnsConnection.on('timeout', log('timeout'));
apnsConnection.on('connected', log('connected'));
apnsConnection.on('disconnected', log('disconnected'));
apnsConnection.on('socketError', log('socketError'));
apnsConnection.on('transmissionError', log('transmissionError'));
apnsConnection.on('cacheTooSmall', log('cacheTooSmall'));
```

I moved the exact same code to the Amazon EC2 instance running Ubuntu 12.04 and it doesn't work there. None of the events above which I handle gets triggered. I checked certificate and key files and paths by printing out the options and apnsConnection objects and there seems no problem there. I don't know what the issue is. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you seeing any console.log messages that might provide clues? Are the cert and key files supposed to point to the same location?

Comment: I have certificate and key in the same file and it works fine on my local machine. I am not getting any error messages. Weird thing is none of the events on the apnsConnection object gets fired.

Comment: @Timothy it seems the connection object is not getting initialized. I am using the node debug module and set DEBUG=apn as an environment variable but I am getting not debug messages.

Comment: Where is deviceTokenArray being defined?

Comment: @Timothy I am defining it in another function after accessing them from the db. What I am grappling with is why none of events is getting triggered.

Comment: Double check that the values are coming through. If it's not sending anything out, none of those events will trigger.

Comment: I checked the deviceTokenArray. There's no problem with values. I dug deeper and found that the connect function in connection.js file in the lib directory of apn module is not able to get the socket connection. Please have a look at line number 188. tls.connect(..) seems to be having some issue. How should I go about finding the problem. Please guide.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35401/discussion-between-ajay-and-timothy-strimple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `node --version` s. On my Mac, homebrew installed v0.10.12 but on the server I was running v0.11.8-pre (by mistake). Apparently the present node-apn doesn't work under the unstable.

I had this same extremely frustrating issue and hunted among firewalls/OpenSSH stuff until I realized the APNS connection still worked through PHP. The Ray Wenderlich script is a quick way to check if the problem is with node or elsewhere.